# Cleanest way to create instances of class dynamically

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, instance

In caluclations.py I have one class called PowerPlant() with

```
def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, ...)
```

and some functions belonging to the class e.g. calculate_supply(self, variable1, variable2).

I'd like to apply the calculations from calculations.py to some power plants stored in a csv file. So far i use the following way...

In simulation.py I read the data from the csv with pd.read_csv()

```
plant_data = pd.read_csv('plants.csv', sep = ';', index_col = False, encoding = 'latin')
```

Then i create a list of lists with

```
# Create list of lists from plant_data DataFrame
list_of_plants = [list(row) for row in plant_data.values]
```

Afterwards I create an instance of the Class PowerPlant with

```
## Outer loop: Iterate over all plants
for row in range(len(list_of_plants)):

    ElectricityOut = []
    Gains = []
    ...

    # Initialise an instance of the plant
    MyPowerPlant = PowerPlant(parameter1 = list_of_plants[row][0], 
                              parameter2 = list_of_plants[row][1], 
                              parameter3 = list_of_plants[row][2], 
                              ...)

    # call some methods from calculations.py 
    ...
```

Any ideas and suggetions how i could do this in a better and more professional way?
Maybe create a object for each plant?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a list like so, no need for range(len())

```
for row in list_of_plants:

    ElectricityOut = []
    Gains = []
    ...

    # Initialise an instance of the plant
    MyPowerPlant = PowerPlant(parameter1 = row[0], 
                              parameter2 = row[0], 
                              parameter3 = row[0], 
                              ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy with accessing the list items with [item] e.g.
list_of_plants[row]**[0]**

As far as i know there is no possibility to access lists via names (use dictionaries for that), but whats with namedTuples?
Is it possible to create instances of a class from namedTuples? If so i would change the list to a namedTuple...

Any suggestions?